# Use setInterval inside async/await with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, async-await, puppeteer

Could anyone answer me, how can I use `setInterval` inside the **page.evaluate** method?

I need to get some dynamic data, and write it into the file every `500ms` 
http://tinyimg.io/i/QjusF8x.png

```js
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://url.com');

// Auth
await page.click(selector.login.tab);
await page.click(selector.login.email);
await page.keyboard.type(settings.username);
await page.click(selector.login.password);
await page.keyboard.type(settings.password);
await page.click(selector.login.button);

// Waiting for loading
await page.waitFor(10000); // TO FIX: there we should wait for loaded element or selector
await page.evaluate(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(document.querySelector('div._captions > p._value').innerText + document.querySelector('div._captions p._hl-value').innerText);
        }, 500);
    });

//await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.jpg'});
await browser.close();})();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need use js a method Promise() like this:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
    await Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setInterval(() => {
          console.log(document.querySelector('div._captions > p._value').innerText + document.querySelector('div._captions p._hl-value').innerText);
      }, 500);
    });
  });
```

If you need finish your timeout you can use the method resolve();